# Hiding Buttons in the HTML Editor Toolbar (AjaxControlToolkit)

Tags: asp.net, css, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I'm trying to hide the buttons that add color, see the picture. I've tried playing with the CSS and all I have managed to do is break the page and hide everything.

http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/HTMLEditor/HTMLEditor.aspx

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Details:** The following should resolve your issue.

**Solution without Masterpage:**

```
<style type="text/css">
     #MainContent_ctl00_ctl01_FixedForeColor {display:none;}
     #MainContent_ctl00_ctl01_FixedBackColor {display:none;}  
</style>
```

**Solution with Masterpage:**

```
<style type="text/css">
    #MainContent_Editor1_ctl01_FixedForeColor {display:none;}
    #MainContent_Editor1_ctl01_FixedBackColor {display:none;}
</style>
```

**Other ways to customise it**

[Customise HTML Editor Control](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/ajax-control-toolkit/htmleditor/how-do-i-use-the-html-editor-control-cs)